# WPF DataGrid sorts columns by name

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid that gets as Itemssource a DataTable:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = transfer.DataTarget.Table.DefaultView;
```

But now the main problem is that he resorts the columns by name. 
As example:
I have a Table with this Columns:
X Y Z U V

I get displayed:
U V X Y Z

How can I disable that. I also tried thisone:

```
private void LoadTransfer(Transfer transfer)
{
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = transfer.DataTarget.Table.DefaultView;
    //spalten selbst genererieren damit diese nicht nach alphabeth geordnet werden
    int index = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn column in transfer.DataTarget.Table.Columns)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = column.ColumnName,
            Binding = new Binding(column.ColumnName),
            DisplayIndex = index++
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to customize the columns manually in xaml? =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new property that holds the weighting of the values represented as integers. Then on the Column with the sorting issue set it's **SortMemberPath** to that property.